# vba loop through array, store values to arrayi

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

I have some data, stored in arrays like

```
Dim arrA, arrB, arrC, arrAi, arrBi
Dim i as integer, x as integer

for i = 1 to 100

    if cells(i,1).value = "criteria" then ' just add value to array when it meets some criteria
        x = x + 1
        arrA(x) = cells(i,1).value
        arrB(x) = cells(i,2).value
        arrC(x) = cells(i,3).value
    end if

next i

redim preserve arrA(1 to x)
redim preserve arrB(1 to x)
redim preserve arrC(1 to x)
```

And the data looks like

arrA:  26.1 40.2 80.3 26.0 41.3 78.7 25.8 40.8 80.0

arrB:  10 11 10 66 67 64 32 32 33

arrC:  1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

Since the values in arrA 26.1, 26.0, 25.8 (position 1, 4, 7) belong to group 1 (referencing to values in arrC at same position), I would like to store 26.1 26.0 25.8 to arrAi and 10 66 32 to arrBi for subsequent calculations.

How can I loop through the 3 arrays and store values to another array as described above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if your arrC has duplicate value then find the index of their respectative position and swap the value of ArrayA and ArrayB

Comment: And what about 2,5,8 position it also belong to the same group(Group 2)?

Comment: Note that `Dim arrA` does not give a dimension to the array. So you should _first do_ a `Dim arrA(100)` and then put data into it. A `Redim` afterwards is no use.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thank you for your reminder.  I shall tidy up my code.  Pretty new to array.

Comment: @MDIsmailHosen thanks for your reply.  For the 2,5,8 positions (and 3,6,9 or even 4,7,11...), I need to perform exactly the same calculation afterwards.  I am thinking about re-using arrAi afterwards.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you just need to use 1 array for storing the data instead of three array..(Array dimension will be 2) then find unique data from array( from third column) and then use that unique data and check if array( third column equal then store that in ArrI...actually you just need to sort the array..

Comment: @MDIsmailHosen very enlightening!  I got a simpler way to handle the problem!  10 millions upvote for this!

Comment: @JohnLiu Good to know that it helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```
Sub handleArraysFromArrays()
 'your existing code...
 'but you fistly must declare
  Dim arrA(1 To 100), arrB(1 To 100), arrC(1 To 100)
 '....
 'your existing code
 '...
 Dim k As Long, kk As Long
 
 ReDim arrAi(1 To UBound(arrA))
 ReDim arrBi(1 To UBound(arrA))
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrC)
    If arrC(i, 1) = 1 Then k = k + 1: arrAi(k, 1) = arrA(i, 1)
    If arrC(i, 1) = 2 Then kk = kk + 1: arrBi(kk, 1) = arrA(i, 1)
 Next i
 ReDim Preserve arrAi(1 To k): ReDim Preserve arrBi(1 To kk)
 Debug.Print UBound(arrAi), UBound(arrBi)
End Sub
```